# JUnit test with Mockito using Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have to write some unit tests and for now i have some but i decide to post a theme because i do not know if the test are correct although they run in Eclipse and EclEmma shows that the tests covered tested code (Highlight green). In one sentence are the unit test correct.

**Method which i will test**

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class UserManager {

@Autowired
private UserManagerDao umDao;

public long getUserId(String email) throws Exception {
        String[] partsOfEmail = email.split("@");
        return umDao.getUserId(partsOfEmail [0], partsOfEmail [1]);
    }
}
```

**Dao class**

```
public class UserManagerDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {


    @Autowired
     private MessageSourceAccessor msa;

    public long getUserId(String userName, String domain) throws Exception {
        String sql = msa.getMessage("sql.select.user_id");
        Object[] params = new Object[] { userName, domain };

        List<Long> result = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql, params, Long.class);

        if (result.size() > 0) {
            return result.get(0);
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

**The test**

```
  @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
  public class UserManagerTest {

     @Mock
     UserManagerDao umDao;

    private String email = "email@email.com";

    @Test
    public void testGetPassportUserId() throws Exception {
            um.getPassportUserId(email);
        }

   }
```

Comment: You might want to google `JUnit tutorial` then.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is 'not quite'.

Your code doesn't seem to be complete - for example, in your test you call `um.getPassportUserId(email)`, but `um` is not declared (I assume it's `UserManager` and injected somehow?), and I see no method called `getPassportUserId`. Ignoring those points, the biggest issue I can see is that you have no assertion in your test; you're not checking that the method returns what you expect.

A common pattern for tests is 'Given, When, Then', meaning that your test should start with a 'given' section - that is, it sets up the mock(s) to return whatever you need, then the 'when' should be your method call and 'then' checks the result of the method call.

So for your example, in Pseudocode, I'd expect something like:

```
@Test
public void testGetPassportUserId() throws Exception {
  // Given...
  String username = "foo";
  String domain = "bar";
  long expectedId = 1L;

  // Use Mockito to tell the mocked umDao to return expectedId when you request "foo@bar"

  // When...
  long actualId = um.getPassportUserId(username + "@" + domain);

  // Then...
  // Use an assertion to ensure that actualId = expectedId
}
```

I've deliberately left this quite open-ended, because there are many correct answers to how you set up the mock (check the Mockito documentation) and even more correct ways to do the assertion (check JUnit documentation, as well as Mockito and Hamcrest).

As an aside, this is a good example of a potential pitfall associated with code coverage tools. Emma is doing exactly the right thing in telling you that all the code has been executed, because it has, BUT you have no way of knowing that the execution was correct, without performing some assertions in your test, so it has given you a false sense of security.

Comment: Is this a correct assert - **assertEquals(1L, user.getId());**

Comment: The form of that is correct, provided your method returns a `user`. From the above it seems like it just returns a `long`, but you certainly have the right idea. My best advice to learn this kind of thing would be to try it and see what happens. Any time you get a passing test straight away, deliberately make it fail, either by changing the 'expected' value in your assert, or changing the code being tested, to convince yourself that a pass is a 'real' pass.